# Redirect directory to file .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a system so this this url:

```
example.com/php/get
```

gets redirected to something like this:

```
example.com/get.php
```

All of this with .htaccess

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/php/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

But it doens't seems to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/php/([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```